# Which grants are required to see privileges for *other* users in information_schema.schema_privileges?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

For a specific database in a MySQL Server 5.5 I would like to view all grants given to *any* user.  To do this I have been reading from the `information_schema.schema_privileges` table using a select statement as follows:

`select * from information_schema.schema_privileges where table_schema='myproject';`

The problem is that I only see my *own* grants for the database.  I am therefore trying to modify my grants such that the grants for *all* users for that database are listed in the results of the select.

In the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/schema-privileges-table.html) it says that the information in the `schema_privileges`table comes from the `mysql.db`table, however also granting `select` for `mysql.db`doesn't seem to make any difference. I still only see my own grants for the database in question.

Does anyone have any ideas which grants are required?

My current grants are as follows:

`show grants;

Grants for myuser@localhost

GRANT USAGE ON . TO 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'XXX'

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP ON myproject.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

GRANT SELECT ON mysql.user TO 'myuser'@'localhost'

GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO 'myuser'@'localhost'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it by just reading out directly from the `mysql.db` table.  It was much simpler in the end!

`select user, host, select_priv, insert_priv, update_priv, delete_priv, create_priv, drop_priv, grant_priv  from mysql.db where Db='myproject';`